# Python MySQL No result set to fetch from

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I am trying to copy the content of a table to another one, but when I execute the query i get this error:

```
raise errors.InterfaceError("No result set to fetch from.")
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from.
```

I tried to modify the code in many ways, but this does not change anything, this is my code:

```
def query(query_string, db_connection):
while True:
    try:
        query_cursor = db_connection.cursor()
        query_cursor.execute(query_string)
        logging.info('Executing query...')
        query_result = query_cursor.fetchall()
        return query_result
    except AttributeError:
        logging.warning('%s Bad credentials' % timestamp)
```

And this is how i call this function:

```
query_to_output_db = rpgen.query("INSERT INTO auth_user.outputdb SELECT * 
FROM auth_user.auth_user", connection_to_input_db)
```

Comment: What are you trying to insert to database? The correct mysql statement for insert is `INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, ...)`, while `SELECT * FROM auth_user.auth_user` will return everything from that database table.

Comment: I want to copy the data in one table to another

Comment: After `query_cursor.execute(query_string)`, you need to commit the statement to save it, `db_connection.commit()`.